# NPM is installing lots of libraries

Tags: node.js

When I use `npm install` base from `package.json` file it installs 337 libraries :/ 
Here is my package file

```
{
  "name": "system_glowna",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "^2.0.0-beta.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.6",
    "zone.js": "0.5.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "del": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp": "^3.8.11",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.5.2",
    "gulp-inject": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-less": "^3.0.3",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^0.10.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.1.6",
    "gulp-minify-html": "^1.0.3",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-replace": "^0.5.3",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.2.4",
    "run-sequence": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

Why it's installing so many libraries? How to limit them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

npm prior to version 3.x installs libraries in a tree structure, so each library has its own node_modules and so on. It could lead (or almost always leads) to duplicated libraries inside different node_modules packages and results in a pretty big node_modules folder. Things get tricky e.g. on Windows, when paths could be too long to delete node_modules easily after.

However, after 3.x release of npm, it uses flat folder structure by default and only if there is any conflict, it installs proper versions for each library.

Note to yourself - the fact that npm installs so many libraries is necessary in order for each library to work properly :)

Comment: And that's my issue. I updated npm and guess now it's using flat folder structure and that's why I though something is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You've told it to install a fairly large number of libraries. Each of those libraries has its own dependencies, which are necessary for that library to run. You can't limit or prevent that unless you just don't want to use the library in question.

Note that installing lots of libraries isn't, by itself, a problem.

Comment: And can I install ex. gulp libraries globally? So those would not be included in project?

Comment: @piernik sure, but keep in mind that anyone else using the project would need to do the same thing. That's (one reason) why installing locally is preferred over globally: there's a much lower risk of "but it works on my machine" problems.